# New to gulp, having issues with compressing

Tags: css, gulp

I'm trying to get a gulp workflow going and I'm confused about something.

I have 3 css files I want to concat and compress. They total 362KB total before I do anything.

This is my gulpfile.js.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concatCSS = require('gulp-concat-css'); 
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('default', function(){
  gulp.src(['public/css/*.css', '!public/css/style.min.css'])
  .pipe(concatCSS('css/style.min.css'))
  .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'))
});

gulp.task('js', function(){
  gulp.src(['public/js/jquery.js',
    'public/js/bootstrap.js',
    'public/js/plugins.js',
    '!public/js/scripts.js'])
  .pipe(concat('js/app.min.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});
```

The css does what it is supposed to, I think but my resulting file is still 292KB. Is that normal? I thought it would save me 30-40% of my file size.

Comment: 30-40% is kind of an arbitrary number, no? If you write styles without much whitespace and very few comments, there's not much to shrink. The only possibly savings, from there, would be compression (gzip).

Comment: Yes, I guess it is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minify doesnt really grant huge rewards.

What you need to use is the uglify plugin, this is where you'll see larger savings.

Once your CSS has been concatenated, run the `gulp-uglify` task on it.

Interested to see what you're savings are.